# Best way to run an ETL on a production MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, etl

We have the following environment:

- 3 servers + 3 replica set servers
- Each server has 3 shards
- Our main collection has around 40,000,000 documents that average at around 6kb
- Our shard key is hashed(_id) - _id being pure BsonID
- We peak daily at around 25,000 I/OPS and low point at around 10,000

We want to run an ETL that loads **all** of the documents on the main collection, do some in memory calculation (in our application tier) and then dumps it into an external DB.

We took the very poor and naive approach and simply loaded documents without a query using limit, skip and batchSize - which was a complete failure (severly hurt our service level - Even though we set the readPreference to secondary).

I was wondering what would be the best approach to be able to load all of our documents without hurting the performance of our database.

The data can be a bit stale (a few seconds delay from the actual data on the primary is fine).

Sorry in advance if this is the wrong part of StackExchange to post my question.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the aggregation framework instead of doing this in your application logic? Please provide a sample document and the expected output.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg we're extracting some fields of our users into Redis. i.e. a user looks like { _id: '12345', Name: 'Marky Mark', Age: 45 }, we'd like to take the _id and Age and store them in Redis for every player

Comment: You can make this a covered query in MongoDB, effectively cashing the values in RAM

Comment: Simply create a compound index over them and use protection to limit the returned fields to `_id`, `name` and `age`: `db.collection.ensureIndex({_id:1, name:1,age:1});db.collection.find(query,{name:1,age:1})`. No need for another DBMS and added complexity.

Comment: Mark, we need to move it to Redis as Mongo can't handle the type of queries we're attempting to do; the example I gave you was just that, an example. Besides my question was how to run an ETL on a live production environment without hurting the quality of service.

Comment: Well, my suggestion was aimed to eliminate the need for ETL  ;) Have to think about that. Can you live with eventual consistency?

Comment: Can you become more accurate about "hurt our service level"? In which way? Are you sure the bottleneck was mongo?

Comment: @Antonis - we saw increased global lock levels, high queued ops and  in on our application's end, a lot of connection timeouts. We then found out that running skip on a large, highly active collection - is a very bad idea.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg it's perfectly reasonable to run it over a period of a few hours, as we already have a process that updates any changes directly to Redis already.

Comment: @Antonis From what we know and with the given constraints, setting the read preference to `secondary` or `secondaryPreferred` should do the trick imho. Any objections?

Comment: You should use the projection-index that Markus suggested and secondary reads. Also use a dedicated mongos for this job not production mongos.  Can you share mongod specs?